# new drywall adjacent to existing wall

Tags: drywall

I have installed some drywall on a door frame that sits adjacent to an existing wall.
It ended up with the new wall not properly aligned with the existing wall as seen in attached pictures.
Any ideas on how I can address the same.
My intention is to create a seamless finish with the existing wall / new drywall
Thoughts / ideas appreciated.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be very difficult to get a good finish using drywall compound slathered on thickly.

I recommend that you remove the drywall you installed and re-frame or shim the doorframe out so that once you place the drywall it will be right in line with the existing drywall.

That should leave you with just a seam to be taped and make finishing it much simpler.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  Any makeshift solution will end up being even more time consuming, and it won't look as seamless as re-doing it.

Comment: Thank you @jwh20 and Frk. I will need to asses the impact of adding shims on the other end of the frame. Will update

Comment: Shimming will increase the overall thickness of the wall. Not a problem UNLESS you are installing a door, then the wall will be thicker then the door jamb and *creative trimming* will be required to deal with gaps.

Comment: @jwh20 it is going to be difficult to add shims. I will have to live with the difference in level.  Is just taping and and applying mud OK   ? I can do it in a way where the tape covers the old wall and new. Will that work ?

Comment: @souser It's ok to do whatever you'll be happy with.  If this were my project I'd tear out as much as needed and redo it properly to achieve a nice looking result.